# Custom post type category returns null

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I created a CPT with CPT UI and register a taxonomy for my CPT.

I get all of this post type

```
<?php 

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'market',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1    );              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
$the_query->the_post(); 
?>
```

everything works fine but `<?php the_category(', '); ?>` returns null.

where is the problem?

Comment: `the_category()` only lists _categories_, from the `category` taxonomy. Use [`the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/) for custom taxonomies.

Comment: @JacobPeattie That would make a good answer with an example :)

Comment: i'm afraid i'm newbie to wordpress. can you  send an example for the_terms in my code? @JacobPeattie